# C# deploy with SQL Lite database to work on other PC

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, deployment

I have a WPF project in which i added SQL Lite via NuGet.

My main goal is to write a function which makes a database if it doesn't exists, then write records to it.

It works fine on my PC, but after i deploy the application, and run it on other PCs, it instantly crashes. 
(I added the *.db file to the solution, but it didn't help either)

(My quessing is it's misses the *.dll files from SQL Lite on the other PC)

What should i do, to make it work on other PCs too?

My code so far:

```
string relativePath = @"getstarted.db";
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + relativePath);
conn.Open();
using (SQLiteCommand mCmd = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [Test Table] (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 'username' TEXT, 'password' TEXT);", conn))
{
   mCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
string Query = "insert into [Test Table](username, password) values('" + "testuser" + "','" + "testpassword" + "')";
SQLiteCommand insercommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, conn);
insercommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
insercommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: "(My quessing is it's misses the *.dll files from SQL Lite on the other PC)" - if you didnt transfer those, you are probably right. Just copy them with your exe.

Comment: I did, but it didn't help either..

Comment: Where are you trying to create the database? You can't just write to folders in program files. Use appdata.

Comment: can you be more specific what should i do/change in appdata ?

Comment: Didn't you have to create the database file before opening it: 'SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("getstarted.db");'

Comment: No, this code that you see above works on my computer.

Comment: You prolly need to give some more info. Catch the error and display the message for instance, or look at event viewer, etc. But as @Andy says, maybe its just an access exception. You tried running it from a non-admin folder? (or as admin)

Comment: As soon as i declare an SQLite object it crashes.

Comment: A user will not usually be able to create files in program files. If you distribute whatever the database file is with your app then that can be in program files. If you instead try and create it then it'll crash and burn. In visual studio, your app isn't running in program files so it can create a database file in some folder relative to the exe in your bin. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30915.c-local-files.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved]

Basically there was 3 things that i changed.

1. I added both the x86 and the x64 SQLiteInterop.Dll-s to the solution.
2. I changed the connectionString to

   string mDbPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "getstarted.db";
3. I changed the constructor to

   SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + mDbPath,true);